# App not responding to received push notification while stopped or in background

Tags: ios, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm implementing the Google Cloud Messaging service. Everything is running correctly, so long as my app is in the foreground. However, if I put the app into the background or stop it altogether, I no longer receive push notifications. I've been all over the [GCM guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client), the [Apple developer pages](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW4), and many SO posts.

In my info.p-list, file, I have `Background fetch` and `Remote notifications` checked. I can't figure out what I am missing.

Here is the method in the AppDelegate that triggers the message handling. It comes mostly from Google. The comment that they make about 'this only works if the app started the GCM service' suggests that something else needs to happen, but I just don't know what it is. I'm not even getting the NSLog output to generate (i.e. the method isn't firing at all).

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
                                                       fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))handler
{
    NSLog(@"Notification received: %@", userInfo);

    //EDIT: looks like this line needs to go!!!!
    // This works only if the app started the GCM service
    //[[GCMService sharedInstance] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];

    // Handle the received message
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                         message:message
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];

    } else {

        if([application currentUserNotificationSettings].types & UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) {
            UILocalNotification * localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            localNotification.alertBody = message;
            localNotification.alertTitle = title;
            localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:2];
            [application presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
        }
    }

    handler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
}
```

Is there anything else that I need to add here? What else do I need to do? I'm stymied. Thanks.

**EDIT - Partial Success**

OK, I discovered that the line:

```
[[GCMService sharedInstance] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];
```

was responsible for stopping notifications from being received while the app was in the background. Commenting it out resolved that problem (it makes me a little nervous, since I don't know what the point of that line is!).

However, when the app is completely stopped, I am still unable to receive these notifications.

**EDIT 2**
Trying to implement the suggestion from Ali, but now I'm confused. As I read the GCM docs, the one that I have been relying on to format my PHP script is the one called [Send Downstream Messages](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream), which I thought was universal for sending to either Android or iOS (the GCM server would handle any differences, maybe?). It works perfectly for Android messages, and works for iOS, other than the issue I am describing when the app is stopped.

Ali makes me think that there is different HTTP formatting required for iOS because he points to the document [Set Up a Client App on iOS](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client), which I've been following religiously for my Objective-C code. It describes *slightly* different, but maybe crucial requirements for the HTTP formatting. Specifically, the URL changes to `https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send` and you add an additional key-value pair `content_type:true` to the message body.

Problem is that as soon as I do this, I get no messages coming through whatsoever. Do I really need to make these changes? Or maybe I'm just implementing them wrong. Here is my PHP script for iOS:

```
<?php
function send_to_ios_devices($link, $api_access_key, $club_id, $notification) {

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . $api_access_key,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $registration_ids = array();

    $sql = "SELECT gcm_registration_token
            FROM USERS
            WHERE device='ios' AND club_id=$club_id";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $reg_id = $row['gcm_registration_token'];
        if ($reg_id != -1) array_push($registration_ids, $reg_id);
    }

    $fields  = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registration_ids,
        'content_available' => 'true',  //<--ADDED THIS LINE
        'notification' => $notification
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    //curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
    $result = curl_exec($ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $recipients = count($registration_ids);
    echo "Push notification sent to " . $recipients . " ios recipient(s).<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `"content_available" : "true"` to your stanza to wake up your application on ios.

Here you can find the complete [doc](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client#receive_messages_through_the_gcm_apns_interface)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I have some questions about it. See my Edit 2 in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS if the application is in the background it is up to APNs whether or not to deliver the notification. If your downstream message requires action by the user you can use priority: "high" which will deliver the notification on iOS even if the app is in the background. Note that in production you should only use High priority for notifications that require user interaction, like a chat message. Use "normal" priority otherwise.

Check the [reference](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) for more.